# Google visualization API doesn't work in IE9

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Visualization API to generate Pie charts. My implementation is working on all the browsers except IE 9.

Not sure if there is any fix for this. When I try to open the page in IE 9, it shows a popup to install the Google chrome frame. But this wasn't working even after installing the chrome frame.

I've even tried the [Google code playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#pie_chart), the same problem in IE 9. So, I confirmed myself that it is something to do with the IE 9.

Has anyone got any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the issue is - Chrome framework plugin hasn't been enabled when I've installed i.e.; by default this plugin was not enabled.

We need to manually enable it (after the installation, when you restart the browser IE displays you a popup showing plugin is ready with two button Enable and Don't enable).

I'm giving you the screenshot of the plugins dialog (You can go to the below screen from Tools -> Manage add-ons)

[image]

After enabling, make sure you restart the browser and refresh the page which is using the Visualization framework.

Unfortunately, end user has to install this in order to get this work in IE 9 which is really a bad user experience.